# Why does my Heroku remote repository all of a sudden supposedly contain something that I don't have locally?

Tags: heroku, github-actions

I created an app on Heroku using the CLI:

```
heroku apps:create --region eu myapp
```

Then in my app's GitHub repository I created a GitHub action to deploy the app on Heroku by pushing a subtree of the repository:

```
git remote add heroku https://heroku:${{ secrets.HEROKU_API_KEY }}@git.heroku.com/myapp.git
git subtree push --prefix path/to/myapp heroku main
```

Then I triggered the action, and it worked perfectly just as intended; the app got deployed on Heroku.

Next, I edited a line of the app's source on GitHub, committed and triggered the pipeline just to test that the action works (as it was configured to trigger on pushes to `main`). The action triggered but then failed with a git error saying that the remote (Heroku remote repository) contains some work that I don't have "locally" (in the GitHub repository where the action was triggered from). I did not push anything to the Heroku remote repository in between, and nobody else has access to the remote either. I just created the app as described. How can the remote have something that I do not have locally?

---

### EDIT1:

After further inspection it looks like the `git subtree push` command produces a different kind of git log when issued from the GitHub actions workflow agent vs. when issued from my local system. The former produces a git log where all of the commits up to that point are somehow squashed into one, whereas the latter produces a full git log including all the commits normally up to that point. Therefore the last commits' hashes are different even though the files are "in the same state" at that point.

Does the discrepancy come from differing `git config --list` or is there something more to this? And what would I need to change in the GitHub workflow's git config to make it not ruin the last commit's hash by doing this not-asked-for squashing? (Assuming the last commit's hash is the issue here.)

Here's the git config that the GitHub workflow agent appears to use:

```
$ git config --list
safe.directory=*
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/mynick/myreponame
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
gc.auto=0
http.https://github.com/.extraheader=AUTHORIZATION: basic ***
branch.main.remote=origin
branch.main.merge=refs/heads/main
```

Comment: Any chance you amended the commit when you changed the code on GitHub? In any case, I _strongly_ urge you to clone this locally. Editing things live on GitHub is very limiting. Figure out what commit hash was originally deployed, then inspect the commit you are trying to push and make sure it has as its parent (or an earlier reachable ancestor) the commit that was first deployed.

Comment: @Chris It appears that the `git subtree push` issued from the GitHub workflow agent produced a single commit where all the commits were somehow squashed into one. If this is the issue, do you have any idea how could I make it not do that? I thought `--squash` would have to be specifically asked for but on GitHub it works differently. I added these notes with the agent's git config to the original post above.

Comment: no, I'm not sure why this behaviour would differ on GitHub. `git subtree split` (which is done automatically as part of `git subtree push`) is supposed to guarantee that the same commits will be generated each time. The documentation says that there is a `--squash` flag, but that it is only valid for `subtree add`, `merge`, and `pull` commands. Perhaps something else is squashing your commits upstream from this?